# General Reasoning Puzzle About a Tank.?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

A tank has been filled with water. On each minute advance the tank will fill double than previous. ie after completing one minute the tank will fill double the water as that in previous.So the tank fill completely in Half an hour ,What was the time required to fill the water in half of the tank?

Answer (score 2):

> 29 minutes because the tank's content doubles every minute. If it is full at the 30 min. mark it must have been half full a minute before.

Comment: Wow Congratulations Radoslav Hristov ,You are Right